# Efficient way of creating recursive paths Python

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I need a simple function to create a path in Python where the parent may or may not exist.

From python documentation os.makedirs will fail if one of the parents exists.

I have written the below method as which works by makes as many sub directories as necessary.

Does this look efficient?

```
def create_path(path):
    import os.path as os_path
    paths_to_create = []
    while not os_path.lexists(path):
        paths_to_create.insert(0, path)
        head,tail = os_path.split(path)
        if len(tail.strip())==0: # Just incase path ends with a / or \
            path = head
            head,tail = os_path.split(path)
        path = head

    for path in paths_to_create:
        os.mkdir(path)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> "From python documentation `os.makedirs` will fail if one of the parents exists."

No, [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) will fail if the directory itself already exists. It won't fail if just any of the parent directories already exists.

Comment: Are these two sentences contradict to each other?

Comment: @AlanSha: Yes, they contradict each other. The quote is from the question and contains a misunderstanding. My comment then tries to correct that misunderstanding and explain what really happens.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my take, which lets the system libraries do all the path-wrangling.  Any errors other than the directory already existing are propagated.

```
import os, errno

def ensure_dir(dirname):
    """
    Ensure that a named directory exists; if it does not, attempt to create it.
    """
    try:
        os.makedirs(dirname)
    except OSError, e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `ok.makedirs` also accepts `exists_ok` which you can set to `True` and avoid implementing this wrapper. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29508062/1467943

Answer (score 4):

Rough draft:

```
import os


class Path(str):
    """
    A helper class that allows easy contactenation
    of path components, creation of directory trees,
    amongst other things.
    """  
    @property
    def isdir(self):
        return os.path.isdir(self)

    @property
    def isfile(self):
        return os.path.isfile(self)

    def exists(self):
        exists = False
        if self.isfile:
            try:
                f = open(self)
                f.close()
                exists = True
            except IOError:
                exists = False
        else:
            return self.isdir
        return exists

    def mktree(self, dirname):
        """Create a directory tree in this directory."""
        newdir = self + dirname
        if newdir.exists():
            return newdir
        path = dirname.split('/') or [dirname]
        current_path = self + path.pop(0)
        while True:
            try:
                os.mkdir(current_path)
            except OSError as e:
                if not e.args[0] == 17:
                    raise e
                current_path = current_path + path.pop(0)
                continue
            if len(path) == 0:
                break
        return current_path

    def up(self):
        """
        Return a new Path object set a the parent
        directory of the current instance.
        """
        return Path('/'.join(self.split('/')[:-1]))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Path: {0}>".format(self)

    def __add__(x, y):
        return Path(x.rstrip('/') + '/' + y.lstrip('/'))
```

Answer (score 4):

With python ( >=3.4.1 ) there is exist_ok parameter for os.makedirs.

> If exist_ok is False (the default), an OSError is raised if the target
>   directory already exists.

So if you use like exist_ok=True there won't be any problem for Recursive directory creation.

> Note : exist_ok comes with python 3.2 on the other hand there was a bug
>   about raising exception even if you set to True. So try using python >=
>   3.4.1 ( fixed in that version )

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, it checks if path exists till n sub directory level, and create directory if not exists.

```
def pathtodir(path):
if not os.path.exists(path):
    l=[]
    p = "/"
    l = path.split("/")
    i = 1
    while i < len(l):
        p = p + l[i] + "/"
        i = i + 1
        if not os.path.exists(p):
            os.mkdir(p, 0755)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but I was not satisfied with the solutions provided since they were mostly too complicated for a simple task.

From the available functions in the library I believe the cleanest we can do is:

```
os.path.isdir("mydir") or os.makedirs("mydir")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while researching a way to make simple directory trees inside of a project directory.

I am somewhat new to Python, and I struggle when data structures get too complex, i.e. nested. It is much easier on my brain's mental mapping to keep track of small lists of iterables, so I came up with two very basic defs to help me with directory tree creation.

The example takes four objects to create a tree:

1. a root directory path = PROJECT_HOME
2. a home path = home (created if it doesn't exist, not overwritten)
3. an iterable of directory names that will go inside of home = branches (created inside of the home, not overwritten)
4. a dictionary of keyed iterables that map onto the branches = leaves (each value created inside of each mapped branch, not overwritten)
5. If any directory exists, it is not overwritten and the error passes silently.

   ```
   import os
   from os.path import join as path_join
   import errno

   def make_node(node):
       try:
           os.makedirs(node)
       except OSError, e:
           if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
               raise


   def create_tree(home, branches, leaves):
       for branch in branches:
           parent = path_join(home, branch)
           make_node(parent)
           children = leaves.get(branch, [])
           for child in children:
               child = os.path.join(parent, child)
               make_node(child)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       try:  # create inside of PROJECT_HOME if it exists
           PROJECT_HOME = os.environ['PROJECT_HOME']
       except KeyError:  # otherwise in user's home directory
           PROJECT_HOME = os.expanduser('~')

       home = os.path.join(PROJECT_HOME, 'test_directory_tree')
       create_tree(home, branches=[], leaves={})

       branches = (
           'docs',
           'scripts',
       )
       leaves = (
           ('rst', 'html', ),
           ('python', 'bash', )
       )
       leaves = dict(list(zip(branches, leaves)))
       create_tree(home, branches, leaves)

       python_home = os.path.join(home, 'scripts', 'python')
       branches = (
           'os',
           'sys',
           'text_processing',
       )
       leaves = {}
       leaves = dict(list(zip(branches, leaves)))
       create_tree(python_home, branches, leaves)

       after_thought_home = os.path.join(home, 'docs', 'after_thought')
       branches = (
           'child_0',
           'child_1',
       )
       leaves = (
           ('sub_0', 'sub_1'),
           (),
       )
       leaves = dict(list(zip(branches, leaves)))
       create_tree(after_thought_home, branches, leaves)
   ```

The directory tree that this example creates looks like this:

```
    dev/test_directory_tree/
    ├── docs
    │   ├── after_thought
    │   │   ├── child_0
    │   │   │   ├── sub_0
    │   │   │   └── sub_1
    │   │   └── child_1
    │   ├── html
    │   └── rst
    └── scripts
        ├── bash
        └── python
            ├── os
            ├── sys
            └── text_processing
```

Answer (score 1):

[This code](https://gist.github.com/samuelsh/b837f8ab8b33c344f01128568dd12019) will generate directory tree with given depth and width, using recursive function call:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

import sys
import os

def build_dir_tree(base, depth, width):
    print("Call #%d" % depth)
    if depth >= 0:
        curr_depth = depth
        depth -= 1
        for i in xrange(width):
                # first creating all folder at current depth
                os.makedirs('%s/Dir_#%d_level_%d' % (base, i, curr_depth))
        dirs = os.walk(base).next()[1]
        for dir in dirs:
                newbase = os.path.join(base,dir)
                build_dir_tree(newbase, depth, width)
    else:
        return

if not sys.argv[1:]:
        print('No base path given')
        sys.exit(1)

print('path: %s, depth: %d, width: %d' % (sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3])))
build_dir_tree(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))
```